# How read in template my json

Tags: angular

I would like read in template angular json ,
this is my data:

```js
  //public test:any; in class

  let liste = [
      {id:0,plage:'8H-9H',isReserver:false},
      {id:1,plage:'9H-10H',isReserver:false},
      {id:3,plage:'9H-10H',isReserver:true},
    ];

    this.test = '{"nomJour":' + 'test' + ', "occupe" : "'+ liste+'" }';
```

```html
json : {{test}} <br/>

nom: {{test.nomJour}}<br/>
isBusy:         
<div *ngFor="let plage of test.occupe  ">
    {{plage.id}}
</div>
<hr/>
```

the name and isBusy is empty ...
How I must correctly build my json ? 
thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is an object tranform to string . You cannot access `{{test.nomJour}}` from a string. make it object

```
this.test = {"nomJour": 'test', "occupe" : liste };
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvb5dz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually create a *json* representation by concatenating strings.

Create your object and then use `JSON.stringify` to make it a valid *json*.

```
let liste = [
   {id:0,plage:'8H-9H',isReserver:false},
   {id:1,plage:'9H-10H',isReserver:false},
   {id:3,plage:'9H-10H',isReserver:true},
];

this.test = JSON.stringify({nomJour: 'test', occupe: liste});
```

Comment: thank's for reply, i try the snippet with stringify, but the isBusy is no change is empty.

Comment: In your object you haven't `isBusy` property. If it is the `occupe` be sure that it has data